# Loading objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class

I have created a class and want to save and load an instance of the object (i.e. after it has been constructed) in my workspace. I have tried using save() and load(), but when I load the object and try to use a function defined on its class, I get the error:

> "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."

The class definition is in my MATLAB path, and so I was wondering if it were possible to load an instance of a class into a clean workspace (I thought maybe when saving the object, it perhaps doesn't store the class?) and use all functions that are defined on that object.

I hope this question isn't too trivial, but I am fairly new to classes and what not... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an error you would get if your class files are not on your path when you load the object. Are you sure all of your files are on your path when you open a clean workspace?

If so, when loading the object, the variable loaded in the workspace should be of type "ClassName". If the class files are not in your path, you'll see the loaded variable as an array.

If your loaded variable is not of type "ClassName", try clearing the workspace (`clear all`), add the class files to the path, and reload the class object.

Comment: Hmm... alright thanks! It's good to know that at least it's possible. I also go to McGill haha...

Comment: Good luck on your OOP adventures! Feel free to say hi if you ever recognize my face on campus!